# suggestion list catching user input delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote below code to retrieve suggestion using ajax when the user is typing. The problem is the call may be too many so I used setTimeout. Is my flow done correctly?

```
 $('.text').on('keydown', function(e) {
                    if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {

                        var suggestionURL = "example.com?q"
                        + $(this).val();
                        setTimeout(function(){ 
                             show_suggestion();
                        }, 1000);

                        function show_suggestion(){

                           // $.ajax..
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: _'Is my flow done correctly? '_ - does it work? Then it's probably correct.

Comment: Your question is phrased poorly, but I believe what you're looking for is AJAX debouncing.  Underscore has a helper for doing this: http://underscorejs.org/#debounce .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` for this. This will ensure that the function is only called it the user has typed more than 3 characters and has stopped typing for at least half a second. Adjust the time as needed:

```js
$(function() {
    var timeOut = 0;
    $(".text")
        .keyup(function() {
        // check input has at least 4 chars
        if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {
          
        // cancel looking, the user typed another character
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        // set a timeout
        // if user doesn't type another key
        // within half a second the function is called
  timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
   show_suggestion();
  }, 500); // change time as needed
          
        }
    });

});

function show_suggestion(){
  alert('user stopped typing, call the ajax');  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text"/><br><br>
<input type="text" class="text"/><br><br>
<input type="text" class="text"/><br><br>
<input type="text" class="text"/><br><br>
```

Comment: when user hit backspace, keyup doesn't catch that. why?

Comment: It wont fire if there are less than 3 characters in the box, if you have 4 chars in the box and backspace it should work, if you have three or less and backspace though it wont get called